# How to grant write access to USB device?

Tags: permissions, usb, root

I'm working with `libfprint` and when running my code that opens a USB device, I get the following error

```
libusb: error [get_usbfs_fd] libusb couldn't open USB device /dev/bus/usb/001/003, errno=13
libusb: error [get_usbfs_fd] libusb requires write access to USB device nodes
```

This is fixed by running the program as sudo/root but how can I allow my normal user to have the same write access as my root user?